# Is there a way to take a biggest key value in dictionary, and print it's item

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an homework to write in Python a program that recieve string of ints, a outputs the most frequent number that appears in string. How to do it?
And another question, please, - in my code i made 10 variables - it doesn't looks laconic, if there a way to loop it or something?
Thank You!

```
# 134523452345234523452345234523455555555555555555555555555555555555
value_1.split(',')
x0=value_1.count('0')
x1=value_1.count('1')
x2=value_1.count('2')
x3=value_1.count('3')
x4=value_1.count('4')
x5=value_1.count('5')
x6=value_1.count('6')
x7=value_1.count('7')
x8=value_1.count('8')
x9=value_1.count('9')
value_1_arr = [x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9]
value_1_arr.sort()
print(value_1_arr)
value_1_dict={x0:0,x1:1,x2:2,x3:3,x4:4,x5:5,x6:6,x7:7,x8:8,x9:9}
print(value_1_dict)
```

thats the output
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 8, 8, 42]
{0: 9, 1: 1, 7: 2, 8: 4, 42: 5}

Comment: Please check `collections.Counter`

Comment: `collections.Counter('134523452345234523452345234523455555555555555555555555555555555555').most_common(1)` gives `[('5', 42)]`

Comment: I imagine the purpose of the assignment is for you to take the time to figure out and attempt solutions to all the questions you are asking. Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

a = '134523452345234523452345234523455555555555555555555555555555555555'

max(Counter(a).items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

or

`Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][0]`

which will return:

`'5'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need only most frequent digit and do not want any `import`s and want to use loop I would do it following way:

```
txt = '134523452345234523452345234523455555555555555555555555555555555555'
examples = txt.count('0')
digit = '0'
for i in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
    if txt.count(i)>examples:
        digit = i
        examples = txt.count(i)
print(digit)
```

Output:

```
5
```

Note that you do not need separate variables for each digit - only 2 variables, one to store most frequent digit so far and how many times it appeared inside string - so you could decide if currently considered digit is more popular or not. Note that your specification is unclear, what should happen if there is more than 1 most frequent digit for example for `111222333` - my code would print digit lowest in value in case of such conflict (`1` in that example). Note that I assigned quantity of `0`s to `examples` rather than doing `examples = 0` and then looping from `0` to `9`, although it would work in this case, it is better to avoid this so-called magic number. Thanks to this you do not need to know smallest possible value.